# How To Get The String Value Of A Particular Row/Column For TextView and Parsing

Tags: android, sqlite

**I have two database related questions**

**Background:**

I can create and delete records.
I can display the entire table and or a single row using StringBuilder.
I can display the entire table in a List using SimpleCursorAdapter.
I can select a desired record from the displayed List, get it's record ID.
I can display the record ID (as a string) in a TextView.

**What I seem not able to do is:**

After selecting an item from the List, getting it's ID, I simply want to Display its *string value*.  I run into the problem of the Query returning a Cursor. When I change or parse the return, I have no success.

Displaying this value is just a step to being able to parse the returned string and use that for some calculations - both calculation and displaying it are the end goals.

**Question 1:**
How do I display the string value of a record at a particular row and column?

**Question 2:**
For this database, I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter to display the List but, only the listed string is clickable - not the full displayed row (meaning, if the contents was only two characters, that's what you've got to click).

Previously, I used a ListAdapter with an ArrayAdapter and selecting anywhere on the Listed Row was acted upon.
So, the question is: how to make the full row clickable?

Any recommendations appreciated, Thanks.
Code follows - BUT, **note** that this snippet is only one of a bazillion try's and this snippet displays what the cursor returns - it wasn't one of the try's at casting or changing it's type to display the contents I want - it was just a test:

```
//ON CLICK
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

  // test for record id#
   String penut = String.valueOf(id); // YES, it gets the record id# 
 //  Maincode.showItem.setText(penut);  // YES, it displays the record id#

   Cursor myGirl = helpDude.db.query(DbAdapter.TABLE_NAME, null,
     "_id=?", new String[]{penut}, null, null, null);

   String outy = String.valueOf(myGirl);

   Maincode.showItem.setText(outy);  

}//end on click
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onListItemClick` listener you should call [`AdapterView#getItemAtPosition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29) which will return the `Cursor` object already positioned at that id for you. You'll have to cast it to a `Cursor`.

So your handler will look similar to this:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {   
  Cursor c = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);

  //use cursor to get data 

}
```

You can read the [List7 ApiDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List7.html) for more details.

If you want to perform extra work on the data in your `Cursor` and display that in your `ListView` you'll have to implement a custom `CursorAdapter`

Some links that provide some help on that:

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/04/custom-widget-adapters.html

http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/

Comment: Thanks but, I must be missing your point - I can already list the contents of the database and from the returned id, I can query the database. I simply want to use a found item from the database (Question 1).  As far as Question 2, I can wait on that one, #1 is far more important to me just now.

Comment: Your current method is wrong regardless of the fact that it's working.  Your question 1 is currently nonsensical, at least to me anyway.

Comment: Thanks. As far as the wrong method - far too many resources use this and your recommended way does not provide any different results for selecting the row - I must still select the text in the row, the row itself is not clickable.  As far as question 1 - I simply want to be able to display the contents of a column and the given row id (and also parse it to do some math).

Comment: Thanks again.  I don't want to display any extra work in the ListView.  I simply want to have, for example, Shoes = the string value of the contents of Row/Col (for a particular row id and column name).  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line of your code:

```
String outy = String.valueOf(myGirl);
```

with:

```
String outy = myGirl.getString(the outy column number);
```

Comment: thanks but, I must not understand the arguments you show. .getString accepts only one arg, an integer.  When you say 'the outy' I don't know what you mean...?

Comment: Oh, I got what you meant.  But, it crashes (simply used 1 for the argument as I have only two col's  0 and 1)

Answer (score 0):

1) It seems, I can only do it the same way I was doing it before (requiring a total of 11 lines of code). But, it works.

Need to march the cursor down through the table, compare the table items (in the desired column) with the desired id and column#, then get it.  It appears I cannot simply get a particular table's cell without doing the march down with the cursor as in: heyDudeGoGetThis(rowId, ColId).

2)  Silly me (I was asleep on this one), just change the width to to fill.

Thanks for your help.